# Arduino callback capture in C#

Tags: c#, callback, arduino, serial-port

So, I am really new with Arduinos and not very good with callback functions at all and could use some help.
I am signalling the arduino to tell me it's current version number using `_serialPort.Write(command, 0, 1);`  where command is a byte array containing the constant for reporting the current version.
It looks like the Arduino does this by sending a callback function using this code

```
case REPORT_VERSION:
    if (currentReportVersionCallback)
      (*currentReportVersionCallback)(currentReportVersionCallbackContext);
    break;
```

How in my C# project can I get the information it callsback when Write() is  void function?  Where would this information go?

Comment: You have to call Read in the serial port to read what the Arduino sends back.

Comment: What would I pass to the read function?  it requires parameters

Comment: You need to make a buffer to hold the amount of data you expect to read and pass that in.